# Flutter App stuck at “Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'… ”

Tags: flutter, gradle

**Please I need Help Solving this Issue**

I have been running my flutter app without issues, but recently I can't run or debug my apps again, each time I try running my app from the terminal or debug console it always get stuck at Flutter App stuck at “Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'”

C:\Development\projects\flutter>cd kchat

C:\Development\projects\flutter\Kchat>flutter run
Running "flutter pub get" in Kchat...                               3.6s
Launching lib\main.dart on GIONEE S10C in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)

Comment: Please I need help solving this issue

Comment: run flutter doctor and paste the output here

Comment: C:\Development\projects\flutter\BroadCapital>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440], locale en-NG)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.54.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

C:\Development\projects\flutter\BroadCapital>

Comment: try to upgrade to flutter 2, run flutter upgrade

Comment: I did that but still same error and more so I had to reverse the upgrade

Comment: this might be an internet connection issue

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem by running
`flutter run -v`
it fixed all the problem but took a longer time, and I can now use
`flutter run`
but still can't use Debug console

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, try to fix your project.
Delete the android folder in your project, having previously saved it in another place, then in the terminal run flutter create your_project_name for the folder in which your project is located.